# Navigation bar does not align and show icons

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm building a navigation bar for my app but it is way off.  Basically, I want my navbar to look something like this:

[image].

But instead this was the result:

[image]

I have written all the necessary code for it but for some reason its giving me this junk.  The following is my code:

bottom_navigation_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:title="Menu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_awards"
        android:title="Awards"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_prizes"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_messaging"
        android:title="Messaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_game"
        android:title="Games"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_game"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contacts"
        android:title="Contacts"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_friends"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

activity_feed.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ca.ozbek.blur.view.FeedActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a minimal, yet **complete** and verifiable version of your code? Thank you!

Comment: @KalaBalik ...all I gave were 2 XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

to your BottomNavigationView

Referenes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html
https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android